# Is there a way to tell ocamlbuild to run my file instead of just produce an executable?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

Right now, if I want to recompile and run an ml file I use

```
ocamlbuild -pkg containers myfile.byte && ./myfile.byte
```

Is there a shorter way to do this? In haskell you can run things just by saying `runghc myfile.hs` and I wonder if ocamlbuild or ocamlfind offer something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All arguments after `--` are passed on to the program to run. So if there are none for your program, do `ocamlbuild -pkg containers myfile.byte --` saving you 14 keystrokes :).

Comment: Thank you :D I am going to do some live coding in a presentation today and saving those 14 characters will be much appreciated.